# how can I get the rest attributes like ATTV, ATTL etc. using S57 Reader?

Tags: gdal, ogr

I'm using GDAL to read S57 files to display them with S52 styles, but I was unable to get the attributions like "ATTV", "ATTL"? Do you know how to get it?

I have put the two supporting files, s57objectclasses.csv, and s57attributes.csv to the correct place following the post http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OGR-to-access-s57-file-missing-attributes-issue-td3742926.html#a3742929 and get the following fields:

```
***************************** 
OGRFeature(WRECKS):2163 
   RCID (Integer) = 2164 
   PRIM (Integer) = 1 
   GRUP (Integer) = 2 
   OBJL (Integer) = 159 
   RVER (Integer) = 1 
   AGEN (Integer) = 540 
   FIDN (Integer) = 2135161787 
   FIDS (Integer) = 688 
   LNAM (String) = 021C7F43FBBB02B0 
   LNAM_REFS (StringList) = (null) 
   FFPT_RIND (IntegerList) = (null) 

-------------------------------------- 
   CATWRK (Integer) = 1 
   CONRAD (Integer) = (null) 
   CONVIS (Integer) = (null) 
   EXPSOU (Integer) = (null) 
   HEIGHT (Real) = (null) 
   NOBJNM (String) = (null) 
   OBJNAM (String) = (null) 
   QUASOU (String) = 2 
   SOUACC (Real) = (null) 
   STATUS (String) = (null) 
   TECSOU (String) = (null) 
   VALSOU (Real) = (null) 
   VERACC (Real) = (null) 
   VERDAT (Integer) = (null) 
   VERLEN (Real) = (null) 
   WATLEV (Integer) = 3 
   INFORM (String) = (null) 
   NINFOM (String) = (null) 
   NTXTDS (String) = (null) 
   SCAMAX (Integer) = (null) 
   SCAMIN (Integer) = (null) 
   TXTDSC (String) = (null) 
   RECDAT (String) = (null) 
   RECIND (String) = (null) 
   SORDAT (String) = (null) 
   SORIND (String) = (null) 
************************************
```

the only missed is "ATTV", "ATTL", do you know how to get it? am I missing something here?